# Redirect in Wordpress based on customer type using cookies or sessions

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies

Our business has two distinct customer groups- we'll call them A and B.  A will go to our normal website and B will be redirected to a specific website we own for those types of customers.  What I'd like to do is when visitors first come to our site is to set a cookie based on whether they click on the picture of Customer type A or the picture of Customer type B.  I think the best way to do this would be to take them to a page after they click one of the pictures and then set a cookie, and then redirect them based on the cookie (or just using a meta refresh for simplicity).  What code could I use on that initial page (we'll call it the home page for simplicity) that would check for the cookie and if they have it, would redirect them to the correct pages (call them Site A and Site B), or if they don't have cookies, would still allow them to click the image that fits them and then be taken to the proper meta refresh?  I don't want anyone without cookies to be stuck in a loop.  If it matters, I am running on a Wordpress site, so PHP or Javascript codes are best.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consider modifying your question accordingly.

Comment: Not a point, much bored!

Comment: As @JasonRoman says, please provide your code. Can you also format your text so its easier to read? A "wall of text" is difficult to read and could put off people who might be able to help.  Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more tips.